# View not hiding when dynamically done in recycler view item

Tags: android

I am using `RecyclerView` to list Items and In each single list displaying an image which will be `Visible/Gone` dynamically. I am using `View.GONE` to hide the view.

In a condition where the image should hide is not working always. It is still showing in screen,and also in debug mode i have checked that and when getting the
`image.getVisiblity()`  it is giving me int value `"8"` which means the view is  `Gone`,But still i can see that image in that list.
It happens only sometimes.

And i tried to use `View.INVISIBLE` and it is working all the time but it is taking the space in layout which is as expected

I am using `sparseArray` to store all the `holders classes`.I have written a method in Adapter and calling this from activity.I am trying to hide the `replayIcon` view

```
public void handleReplayButton(int pos,Boolean isDisplay) {

   Holder holder = holderSparseArray.get(pos);

   if(holder != null) {
       if (isDisplay != null && isDisplay == true) {
           holder.playIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           holder.pauseIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           holder.replayIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       } else if(isDisplay != null && isDisplay == false) {
           holder.playIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           holder.pauseIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           holder.replayIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       } else {
           holder.playIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           holder.pauseIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           holder.replayIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
   }
```

}

Here it is going to the last `else statement` what i want and it is setting the view to GONE.and when i call `holder.replayIcon.getVisibility()` it is giving me int 8 but,still i can see the icon

Comment: Post the relevant code

Comment: I think, you are facing with some logic bugs. It would be better if you post relevant code snippet specially RecyclerAdapter class.

Comment: How are you hiding your ImageView? Maybe the `onBindViewHolder` method is overriding it back to being visible? Can you share your Adapter code?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifydatasetchanged) to refresh the list in the recycler view.

But since you have to remove an item, you can also use [`notifyItemRemoved`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifydatasetchanged)

Also, if you are using `setVisibility()` method to HIDE the view, then make sure you also set the view as VISIBLE for valid items, because the items are reused in a recycler view.

For more : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: please check my code you can find it.And also i do not want to remove item i want a view to hide in a single Item in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling invisible at the end of one statement which makes it visible and vice versa.

Or

You can also try to put notifydatasetchanged().

Comment: its a bad approach to call notifyDataSetChanged() if you want to update only one item. It will take a lot of memory to redraw the all views. Check my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

If you will call *notifyDataSetChanged()* - it will update all the items in the list. 
Don't do that if you need to update special items by index because it will take a lot of memory to redraw the all views.

Instead like the guys wrote before you should use *notifyItemChanged(), notifyItemInserted() or notifyItemRemoved()*.

If you want to update couple views use can use *notifyItemRangeChanged(), notifyItemRangeRemoved() or notifyItemRangeInserted()*.

[You can read more about it here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter)

Also there is one way to it. You can use **DiffUtils** callbacks.

Pretty good approach that work with animation already.

[DiffUtils Calbacks](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/using-leanbacks-diffcallback-77d47949212b)